# How to enable keyboard navigation only when JSSOR slider has focus

Tags: accessibility, jssor, keyboard-navigation

I have two JSSOR sliders on a page.  I need my page to be keyboard navigable for "accessibility" purposes.  So I set $ArrowKeyNavigation to true, and now I can keyboard navigate both sliders.  Trouble is, the arrow keys move through both sliders at the same time.  There is no way to step through just one of the two sliders.

My first thought was adding a $(elem).focus() handler on either the slider itself, or the container around the slider, then in the handler, update the $ArrowKeyNavigation setting.  However, there is no API for getting/setting the $ArrowKeyNavigation property, so it seems like the whole JSSOR Slider must be completely recreated.  I did this also, but the process of doing that interferes with the current focus, so you end up not being able to  past the slider.

Is there a more reliable way to enable keyboard navigation in JSSOR slider on focus, so that two sliders may co-exist on a page and be independently controlled by the keyboard?

Comment: For now, there is no option to set $ArrowKeyNavigation value dynamically.

Comment: The jssor slider is really badly implemented from a keyboard handler perspective in that it is registering its keyboard handler globally against the document and not differentiating between multiple sliders. Modify the jssor source code or choose another library.